# Get words wrapped in <b> tags from string using PHP

Tags: php

In PHP I have a string: "Latest **news**, headlines, analysis, photos and videos on Barack **Obama**"

I want to parse the string and add all the bolded words (the words with a < b > tag around it) to an array. In this case, "news" and "Obama"

Here is what I have so far, although I imagine it could be done in a more elegant/"right" way with regular expressions or something.

```
<?php

$string = "Latest <b>news</b>, headlines, analysis, photos and videos on Barack <b>Obama</b>";
$words = explode(" ", $string);
$boldedWords = array();
foreach($words as $word){
   if( strpos($word, "<b>" ) !== false) { 
       if(!in_array($word, $boldedWords)){
            array_push($boldedWords, $word);
       }
   }

?>
```

Comment: The HTML/XML parsing can also work, but requires a lot of extra steps and for my purposes the answers below are the best answers

Comment: 3 lines is not a lot of extra steps https://3v4l.org/tuTSj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a while and in the meantime you've got quicker answers addressing your concern. My approach uses `preg_match_all` instead of `preg_match`.

Here's a [demo](https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/EjP) to play with the input string and pattern in case you want to further explore.

```
<?php

$string = "Latest <b>news</b>, headlines, analysis, photos and videos on Barack <b>Obama</b>";

$o = preg_match_all('/<b>(?<bolded_text>.+?)<\/b>/', $string, $boldedWords);

//if no errors occured performing the match (in that case $o will contain the number of matches)
if($o !== false){
    
    //this is the array containing the raw matched text including the <b></b> tags
    var_dump($boldedWords[0]);
    /*
    outputs:
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(11) "<b>news</b>"
      [1]=>
      string(12) "<b>Obama</b>"
    }
    */

    //this is the array containing the bolded text but stored with no <b></b>
    var_dump($boldedWords[1]);
    /*
    outputs:
    array(2) {
       [0]=>
       string(4) "news"
       [1]=>
       string(5) "Obama"
    }
    */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**It's working fine**
*I think this is best way*

```
preg_match_all('/<b>(.*?)<\/b>/s', $string, $boldedWords);
```

without foreach

```
echo $boldedWords[1]
```

Comment: This is not the best way. Look into parsers.

Comment: Very close, when I try this and print_r($boldedWords) I get "Array ( [0] => news [1] => news )". It looks like it missed "Obama" and gave "news" twice

Comment: "Obama" is not ending up in the $boldedWords array

Comment: oh sorry use 
preg_match_all('/<b>(.*?)<\/b>/s', $string, $boldedWords);
        var_dump($boldedWords[1]);

Comment: $string = "Latest <b>news</b>, headlines, analysis, photos and videos on Barack <b>Obama</b>";
 
        preg_match_all('/<b>(.*?)<\/b>/s', $string, $boldedWords);
        var_dump($boldedWords[1]);